# Loopback Remote Method Constantly Adding {id} into the Route

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I'm just starting with Loopback.
I have been successfully able to follow one course about LoopBack, and many tutorials across its documentations.

Now, when trying to create a real remote method, I'm failing at the very beginning.

I want to create a route that goes like this:

```
/workspaces/cards
```

Which is supposed to read from some query strings which I can pass, and it will give me a 'Swiss Knife' type of route, which I can later on apply at some filtering fields I'll have in my front end application.

The way I intend to use is like so:

```
/workspaces/cards?find=teams
/workspaces/cards?find=projects
/workspaces/cards?find=users
/workspaces/cards?find=countries
```

The first problem arises soon after utilizing the CLI command for creating remote methods: lb remote-method.

It does create the correct data at my workspaces.json file, and I have copy-pasted the boilerplate method into my workspaces.js file.

Doing it just from what the copy-paste provided, it does nothing. Nothing will appear at my explorer.

So, I tinkered a bit with my workspace.js and workspace.json files, until I was able to make the respective route appear at the explorer.

The first problem is that I'm only able to make the desire route appear like so:

```
/workspaces/{id}/cards
```

And, as stated above, I want it like so:

```
/workspaces/cards
```

I have tried many things, and so far I haven't been able to successfully accomplish this.

The second problem is that it will always require the ID, I take it's behaving like that because of the route, which is stubbornly appearing with that /workspaces/{id}/cards

Here's how my .js and .json files are looking like (for the parts that matter)...

workspace.js

```
module.exports = function(Workspace) {
    Workspace.cards = function (find, name, callback) {
        var result = {};

        callback(null, result);
    };


    Workspace.remoteMethod(
        'cards',
        {
            http: { "path": "/cards", "verb": "get" },
            accepts: [
                { arg: "find", type: "string", required: false, http: { source: "query" } },
                { arg: "name", type: "string", required: false, http: { source: "query" } }

            ],
            returns: { arg: "result", type: "Object", "root": true }
        }
    );

};
```

workspace.json

```
  //...
  "methods": {
    "prototype.cards": {
      "accepts": [
        {
          "arg": "find",
          "type": "string",
          "required": false,
          "description": "To match a search for an specific workspace|project|team|user|county",
          "http": {
            "source": "query"
          }
        },
        {
          "arg": "name",
          "type": "string",
          "required": false,
          "description": "To match a search fro an specific name of workspace|project|team|user|country",
          "http": {
            "source": "query"
          }
        }
      ],
      "returns": [
        {
          "arg": "result",
          "type": "object",
          "root": true,
          "description": ""
        }
      ],
      "description": "General Filtering for Everyting",
      "http": [
        {
          "path": "/cards",
          "verb": "get"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

What did I miss?

Here's my current loopback version:

4.2.0 (generator-loopback@5.8.2 loopback-workspace@4.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Just removed the data from the json file and everything started working.

Comment: what was wrong in this setup is that you defined remote method twice: in js code and in json. You need to do one or another. And if you are adding `prototype` keyword it means that you will refer to the endpoint via the model with certain ID, so you route looks like: workspace/{id}/cards. If you'd remove `prototype` it would be fine, but as I wrote - you need to define that remote method once